# Unable to render SVG as dataURI in Highcharts marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Unable to render SVG as dataURI

```
{
  marker:
   {
    symbol: "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>')"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported format for SVG marker. All supported formats are described in [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/) linked in [this API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.symbol). To have SVG marker symbol use predefined symbol available via additional `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols` property, like `cross` in the mentioned demo.